# Angular 2 create dynamic formcontrol that contains formarray

Tags: html, angular, forms

I have a reactive input form with a dynamic amount of inputs that I need to add form controls to.

The parent control `Mammals` will contain a variable amount of `MammalId`'s, and each MammalId will contain a FormArray of variable length.

I have created typescript code that will generate the form as I described, however, I haven't been able to set my form to my HTML.

And an example of my generated form:

[image: example]

I've tried mapping the form to my html in the following way:

```
<form [formGroup]="inputForm">
  <div *ngFor="let mammal of Mammals; let i = index">
    <div *ngFor="let id of mammal.ids; let z = index">
      <!-- parent form control -->
      <div [formGroupName]="mammals">
        <!-- mammals[i].id resolves to 'mammalIdx' -->
        <div [formGroupName]="mammals[i].id">
          <!-- this should map as the controls Form Array -->
          <input [formControlName]="z">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But when I try and run this, I get:

> Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

How can I set my html to my form values?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The parent control Mammals will contain a variable amount of MammalId's, and each MammalId will contain a FormArray of variable length.**

As per my understand the arry you expected may be like this

```
  [  
   {  
      "Mammals":[  
         {  
            "mammalId":[  
               {  

               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

for that above array the form will be like this

```
    this.inputForm = this.fb.group({
   Mammals: this.fb.array([}
   mammalId: this.fb.array([{
      z: ''
      }
   ])}
  ])
})
```

for that above array html should be like this

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="inputForm">
<div formArrayName="Mammals">
  <div *ngFor="let mammal of inputForm.get('Mammals'); let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
  <div formArrayName="mammalId">
    <div *ngFor="let id of mammal.get(mammalId); let z = index" [formGroupName]="z">
      <!-- parent form control -->

        <!-- mammals[i].id resolves to 'mammalIdx' -->

          <!-- this should map as the controls Form Array -->
          <input [formControlName]="z">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

It may be helps you